# How to remove empty lines in my console Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have a laravel installation, the console was working fine at start, then after a while i must have done something that made the console spit some extra empty lines. Here is what it looks like

```
D:\PATH_TO_MYAPP>php artisan migrate:refresh --seed






                                                Migration table not found.
Migration table created successfully.
...
```

**How do i remove these extra lines?**

Comment: Did you adjust the size of your shell window? This may have to do with Window's command prompt rather than laravel's output.

Comment: @m_kinsey No i am using phpstorm, it stays the same. And i dont think it explains so many empty lines.

Comment: You may have made some new lines before and/or after `<?php ?>` tags. Check your `artisan` file at the project root. Also, make sure you don't close your php tags in class files and anything that isn't outputting html.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `artisan` file at the project root and look at the very top. Are there any blank lines before the `<?php` tags? If so, remove them. Now check at the bottom of the file. Are you closing the php tag with `?>`? If so, remove the `?>`, you don't need them and any new line that comes after that is going to the console for output.